# Foundation Wall Question

Tags: concrete, walls, foundation, footings, rebar

I’m new to building so I am here with a foundation question. We hired a contractor for our concrete pour on a foundation wall. The finished result is attached in the picture below.

Other than the exposed rebar that I am planning to patch on my own, there is exposed 2x4s in the footings. I can’t find anything online as to why there are 2x4s left in the footings. Any idea what those are for? Are they a hazard to leave in?

My contractor says to leave everything as is and backfill but it just doesn’t look right to me. The rebar for one would rust. Additionally, wouldn’t the 2x4s rot underground even if pressure treated? What should I do next with the foundation?

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Comment: One exposed rebar at the edge of the slab matters not at all.

Comment: Its not a neat job, but the rebar is probably not very effective anyway.

Comment: So get a structural engineer or building surveyor to check it before you continue, relying on netizens for important things is NOT smart.

Comment: Has your local building inspector been called in to give it a once-over? In general, I'd agree 100% with you - your inspector can be the "bad guy" and get this fixed without the contractor being overly mad at you.

Comment: Is this being built using stamped drawings?

Comment: It's a sloppy job. My big concern is the wood. It's never good to bury wood underground.

Comment: Thanks for your input so far. I’ll use this comment to answer and reply to the above comments. 

My county has no building code which means they won’t come out during the building process apparently. We we decided to do research and gain advice before hiring someone else for their opinion. There are no stamped drawings. 

What could you even do with the wood at this point?